# Форма не отправляет данные или зацикливается проверку. Как решить?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Делаю проверку формы.
Сначала ищутся дубли в БД при помощи AJAX.
После проверки на дубли подключается основная проверка всех полей. 
Если использовать

> $('#reg-form form').off('submit').submit();

при отсутствие ошибок при первом нажатии ничего не срабатыает, при втором нажатии на Submit отправляется форма. 
Если использовать

> $('#reg-form form').submit();

То зацикливается проверка формы.

Тыкните пожалуйста, где я неправильно делаю. Спасибо

```js
var errorRules = { },   // Объект с правилами
        
    errorMes = { },   // Объект с описанием ошибок
    
    errorReg = { };  // Объект с ошибками (в каких полях допущены ошибки и какие именно)

    var oFuncValid = { }; // Функции с проверкой данных формы  
          
    function notDoubleCheck () {  /* вызов функций проверки, кроме double*/
        /* Перебираются все поля в форме и проверяются по имеющимся функциям*/
        
        /* Если ошибок нету, то удаляется обработчик submit и вызывается обычный submit*/
        if (matchError === 0) {
            console.log('Ошибок нет.'); 
            $('#reg-form form').off('submit').submit();
        }
    };
        
        
    $('#reg-form form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Останавливаю отправку формы
        
        var double = []; /* количество проверок на дубли*/
        $.each(errorRules, function(key,value) {
            if ('double' in value) {
                double.push( 
                    oFuncValid.double( key , $('#reg-form form input[name='+key+']').val() )
                );
            }
        });
        
        /* Вызываем AJAX проверку на дубли в БД, после AJAX идёт основная проверка полей */
        if ( double.length > 0 ) { 
            Promise.all(double)
                .then( resolve => {
                    // После AJAX проверки на дубли в БД вызывается основная проверка полей
                    notDoubleCheck();
                })
                .catch ( reject => {
                    // обработка ошибок выполнения запросов
                    console.log('Какая-то ошибка');
                });
        } else {
            notDoubleCheck();
        }  
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="reg-form" class="reg-form" style="display: block;">
    <form action="/" method="post">
        <div>
            <label for="username">Username</label><div class="errorReg"></div>
            <input type="text" name="username" value="" title=" ">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="password">Password </label><div class="errorReg"></div>
            <input type="password" name="password" value="" title="">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="email">Email </label><div class="errorReg"></div>
            <input type="text" name="email" value="" title=" ">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="skype">Skype</label><div class="errorReg"></div>
            <input type="text" name="skype" value="" title="">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="submit">&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Не надо запускать событие `submit`по нажатию кнопки `register`.
Лучше повесить на эту кнопку обработчик события `click`, а событие `submit` инициировать в скрипте после всех проверок

```js
var errorRules = { },   // Объект с правилами
        
    errorMes = { },   // Объект с описанием ошибок
    
    errorReg = { };  // Объект с ошибками (в каких полях допущены ошибки и какие именно)

    var oFuncValid = { }; // Функции с проверкой данных формы  
          
    function notDoubleCheck () {  /* вызов функций проверки, кроме double*/
        /* Перебираются все поля в форме и проверяются по имеющимся функциям*/
        
        /* Если ошибок нету, то удаляется обработчик submit и вызывается обычный submit*/
        const matchError = 0;
        if (matchError === 0) {
            console.log('Ошибок нет.'); 
            $('#reg-form form').submit();
        }
    };
        
        
    $('[name="submit"]').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Останавливаю отправку формы
        
        var double = []; /* количество проверок на дубли*/
        $.each(errorRules, function(key,value) {
            if ('double' in value) {
                double.push( 
                    oFuncValid.double( key , $('#reg-form form input[name='+key+']').val() )
                );
            }
        });
        
        /* Вызываем AJAX проверку на дубли в БД, после AJAX идёт основная проверка полей */
        if ( double.length > 0 ) { 
            Promise.all(double)
                .then( resolve => {
                    // После AJAX проверки на дубли в БД вызывается основная проверка полей
                    notDoubleCheck();
                })
                .catch ( reject => {
                    // обработка ошибок выполнения запросов
                    console.log('Какая-то ошибка');
                });
        } else {
            notDoubleCheck();
        }  
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="reg-form" class="reg-form" style="display: block;">
    <form action="/" method="post">
        <div>
            <label for="username">Username</label><div class="errorReg"></div>
            <input type="text" name="username" value="" title=" ">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="password">Password </label><div class="errorReg"></div>
            <input type="password" name="password" value="" title="">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="email">Email </label><div class="errorReg"></div>
            <input type="text" name="email" value="" title=" ">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="skype">Skype</label><div class="errorReg"></div>
            <input type="text" name="skype" value="" title="">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="submit">&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="button" name="submit" value="Register">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```